# XNA only using 1 core for 4 ThreadPool tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, xna, threadpool

I'm creating a physics simulation, which is meant to be realistic, and I have it working correctly, but the framerate drops off quite quickly.

I'm iterating through each of the objects, and then again for each of those objects.

I'm not sure why this would be the case, since the number of operations in each frame remains the same. The only thing of which I can think, is that the threading is the problem. I have the iteration split into four parts, and I have one quarter of the list being calculated on 4 separate threadsw, but when I check task manager, I'm only really using one core.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
private void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Bodies.Count; i++)
    {
        Bodies[i].Update(gameTime);
    }

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CalculatePhysics0));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CalculatePhysics1));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CalculatePhysics2));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CalculatePhysics3));
}

private void CalculatePhysics0(object o)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Bodies.Count/4; i++)
    {
        Body body = Bodies[i];
        g.ApplyTo(ref body, Bodies);
    }
}

// 3 other methods exactly the same, but iterating their portion of the list
```

I'm not very experienced with multithreading. I *can* deal with the problems that arise from its use, though. I can see that the problem may be that the `ThreadPool` is not a good way to achieve my desired effect, which is to iterate through the list concurrently between threads.

Comment: I don't think it's relavent, but I'm using xna GS 4.0

Comment: Thanks, it is very relevant as my answer is only available in 4.0+.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but QueueUserWorkItem has a second parameter which lets you pass a value into your function in the "object o" argument. This could let you avoid the duplicate functions in favor of a single piece of code.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski true, I had considered doing that, but I first wanted to make sure that my methodology was accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx), which helps make most of this much easier. This should be available in XNA 4.0+

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>CalculatePhysics0);
```

I believe the default behavior should work, but you can specify the [TaskCreationOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx)

If that does not work, then you can use a [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx):

```
var scheduler = new TaskScheduler{MaximumConcurrencyLevel=4};
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>CalculatePhysics0, null, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);
```

Comment: I've implemented this, and I see no performance increase. Also, task manager still tells me that only one core is being used out of 12.

Comment: @annonymously OK, I have updated my answer to use a TaskScheduler. I am surprised the default one does not distribute appropriately...it has when I have used it in the past. Is the processing happening quickly, are the methods sharing any variables...if not, it might be a limitation on the XNA part

Comment: I can't even get the task scheduler to compile. It says the `TaskScheduler` class is abstract, and that the `MaximumConcurrencyLevel` is read only

Answer (score 0):

In regards to a comment you've left on another answer: more threads != performance increase.  You may be surprised how many things actually perform better in serial rather than in parallel.  Of course, that doesn't mean that your code can't benefit from multiple threads on different cores, just that you shouldn't assume adding more threads will magically cause your processing throughput to increase.

It's difficult to say what will help your code perform better, without being able to look at more of it.  First, it's helpful to know a little bit about the threading model in .NET.  I would recommend you read about it, since I can't go into much detail here.  A thread in .NET is not necessarily a native thread.  That is to say that by the time you queue the third physics method in the `ThreadPool`, the first might be done, and so it will just use the thread already created.  Of course, then there's the time where you queue a task right before another one finishes and an additional (costly) native thread has to be created.  In that case, it's possible that less threads might have been better.

The idea of abstraction goes further when you look at the Task Parallel Library, where each task may seem like a thread, but really is much further from it.  Many tasks can wind up running on the same thread.  You can get around this by hinting to the `TaskFactory` that it's a long running task, ie `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)`, which causes the scheduler to start this task on a new thread (this, again, might not be better than just having the runtime schedule it for you).

All this being said, if your work takes enough time to process, it *will* wind up running on a separate thread if you're queuing it with the `ThreadPool`.  If the work happens fast enough, though, it would appear that only one thread or one core is being used.

- What led you to the conclusion that that you're only using one core?
- Was it only what you saw from Task Manager?  That's hardly a conclusive result.
- Did you try adding a column to the Task Manager detail tab for threads, and actually check if your code is spawning additional threads or not?
- I also see that you're iterating over the array of `Bodies` twice, is there any particular reason you can't update the bodies with the `GameTime` in parallel as well (perhaps some limitation in XNA)?

All of the above is just a shot in the dark though.  If you *really*, and I mean **really** want to know where any performance issues lie, you'll profile your code with a decent profiler, like [Ants by RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), [dotTrace by JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), or if you have the Premium or above edition of Visual Studio, the analyzer built right into your IDE.

I'm not sure your problem is where you think it is, and in my experience, it rarely is.  I hope that some of my brain dump above can be of some help to you.